# write it in one sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 2 columns: name and indication(Success or Failed),
I need to create single SQL statement to get result with3 columns: Name,#total occurrences of item and # of Failere

How can I write it in one single sql statement

Comment: did you try it by yourself? Please check "SELECT ... GROUP BY" in google.

Comment: You need to give us more information: what is the tables' structure and the relationship between them.

Comment: why is a sub-select impossible? has it really to be one line in form of one query, or is it ok to have subselects?

Comment: yes and my question is how I get two diffrent statement and how can i make it into one statement

Comment: Please post desired output

Comment: table structue: name nvarchar(50), Indication(bit) thats all.

Comment: sergey I know how to use group by but I need to use the count of the failere and the count of the names in one query how can i do it?

Comment: desire output: prod1, 2 , 1 (prod 1 has 2 instances one failre and one success and the 1 represent failre)

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.name, count(t.name),count(case When t.indication= 1 Then t.indication end) from     table1 t
group by t.name
```

This is [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/860d4/4)

Comment: Lacking the ELSE 0 will produce NULL instead of 0.

Comment: @Quandary can you tell how?

Comment: Ah, never mind. I used sum instead of count. Count doesn't produce NULL, only sum does.

Comment: +1 On a side remark you could write it as simple as this: select t.name, count(*),count(case When t.indication= 1 Then 3 end) from
table1 t
group by t.name

Answer (score 1):

I have made an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15f071/1) to demonstrate:

```
SELECT
  name,
  COUNT(success) AS `count`,
  SUM(CASE success WHEN 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `failures` 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: you are counting a value of a column instead of the column

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it gets you the results you want:

```
SELECT X.name, COUNT(X.name), 
    (SELECT COUNT(Y.indication) FROM table_name Y WHERE Y.indication = 1 AND Y.name = X.name)
FROM table_name X
GROUP BY X.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      table_name.name
     ,COUNT(table_name.name) AS cnt 
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN table_name.indication = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FailCount
FROM YOUR_TABLE AS table_name 
GROUP BY table_name.name
```

Actually, it depends on how you save indication.
If you use a bit field, with true (1) = failed and false (0) = success  then you can do this:

```
   SELECT 
          table_name.name
         ,COUNT(table_name.name) AS cnt 
         ,SUM(CAST(table_name.indication AS integer)) AS FailCount
    FROM YOUR_TABLE AS table_name 
    GROUP BY table_name.name
```

Comment: Your `CASE` switch is redundant. If indication is 1, then you count 1. Otherwise (i.e. when it's 0), you count 0. You could just `SUM` over the `indication`.

Comment: @kba: Yes, but you assume "indication" is a number with zero or one.

Comment: @Quandary He wrote in a comment to his own question that indication is indeed a bit field.